# Perlin noise returning bigger values than [-1;1] interval

Tags: c++, perlin-noise

so i tried to implement perlin noise in c++ and render it in raylib. well, i failed to implement it correctly and get crazy results.

[image: picture 1]]

After printing several variables i detected that perlinNoise function returns bigger values than [-1; 1] interval. can anyone tell me why it is doing that? maybe i dont calculate gradient vectors correctly? because as i see values are not repeating.

```cpp
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "raylib.h"

using namespace std;

int p[] = {
    151, 160, 137, 91,  90,  15,  131, 13,  201, 95,  96,  53,  194, 233, 7,
    225, 140, 36,  103, 30,  69,  142, 8,   99,  37,  240, 21,  10,  23,  190,
    6,   148, 247, 120, 234, 75,  0,   26,  197, 62,  94,  252, 219, 203, 117,
    35,  11,  32,  57,  177, 33,  88,  237, 149, 56,  87,  174, 20,  125, 136,
    171, 168, 68,  175, 74,  165, 71,  134, 139, 48,  27,  166, 77,  146, 158,
    231, 83,  111, 229, 122, 60,  211, 133, 230, 220, 105, 92,  41,  55,  46,
    245, 40,  244, 102, 143, 54,  65,  25,  63,  161, 1,   216, 80,  73,  209,
    76,  132, 187, 208, 89,  18,  169, 200, 196, 135, 130, 116, 188, 159, 86,
    164, 100, 109, 198, 173, 186, 3,   64,  52,  217, 226, 250, 124, 123, 5,
    202, 38,  147, 118, 126, 255, 82,  85,  212, 207, 206, 59,  227, 47,  16,
    58,  17,  182, 189, 28,  42,  223, 183, 170, 213, 119, 248, 152, 2,   44,
    154, 163, 70,  221, 153, 101, 155, 167, 43,  172, 9,   129, 22,  39,  253,
    19,  98,  108, 110, 79,  113, 224, 232, 178, 185, 112, 104, 218, 246, 97,
    228, 251, 34,  242, 193, 238, 210, 144, 12,  191, 179, 162, 241, 81,  51,
    145, 235, 249, 14,  239, 107, 49,  192, 214, 31,  181, 199, 106, 157, 184,
    84,  204, 176, 115, 121, 50,  45,  127, 4,   150, 254, 138, 236, 205, 93,
    222, 114, 67,  29,  24,  72,  243, 141, 128, 195, 78,  66,  215, 61,  156,
    180, 151, 160, 137, 91,  90,  15,  131, 13,  201, 95,  96,  53,  194, 233,
    7,   225, 140, 36,  103, 30,  69,  142, 8,   99,  37,  240, 21,  10,  23,
    190, 6,   148, 247, 120, 234, 75,  0,   26,  197, 62,  94,  252, 219, 203,
    117, 35,  11,  32,  57,  177, 33,  88,  237, 149, 56,  87,  174, 20,  125,
    136, 171, 168, 68,  175, 74,  165, 71,  134, 139, 48,  27,  166, 77,  146,
    158, 231, 83,  111, 229, 122, 60,  211, 133, 230, 220, 105, 92,  41,  55,
    46,  245, 40,  244, 102, 143, 54,  65,  25,  63,  161, 1,   216, 80,  73,
    209, 76,  132, 187, 208, 89,  18,  169, 200, 196, 135, 130, 116, 188, 159,
    86,  164, 100, 109, 198, 173, 186, 3,   64,  52,  217, 226, 250, 124, 123,
    5,   202, 38,  147, 118, 126, 255, 82,  85,  212, 207, 206, 59,  227, 47,
    16,  58,  17,  182, 189, 28,  42,  223, 183, 170, 213, 119, 248, 152, 2,
    44,  154, 163, 70,  221, 153, 101, 155, 167, 43,  172, 9,   129, 22,  39,
    253, 19,  98,  108, 110, 79,  113, 224, 232, 178, 185, 112, 104, 218, 246,
    97,  228, 251, 34,  242, 193, 238, 210, 144, 12,  191, 179, 162, 241, 81,
    51,  145, 235, 249, 14,  239, 107, 49,  192, 214, 31,  181, 199, 106, 157,
    184, 84,  204, 176, 115, 121, 50,  45,  127, 4,   150, 254, 138, 236, 205,
    93,  222, 114, 67,  29,  24,  72,  243, 141, 128, 195, 78,  66,  215, 61,
    156, 180};

float fade(float t) { return t * t * t * (t * (6 * t - 15) + 10); }

float lerp(float a0, float a1, float t) { return a0 + t * (a1 - a0); }

float dotp(Vector2 a, Vector2 b) { return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y; }

Vector2 grad(int a) {
  Vector2 v[8] = {
      {sqrt(3) / 2.0, 0.5f},        {-sqrt(3) / 2.0, 0.5f},
      {-sqrt(3) / 2.0, -0.5f},      {sqrt(3) / 2.0, -0.5f},
      {sqrt(2) / 2, sqrt(2) / 2},   {-sqrt(2) / 2, sqrt(2) / 2},
      {-sqrt(2) / 2, -sqrt(2) / 2}, {sqrt(2) / 2, -sqrt(2) / 2},
  };

  return v[a % 8];
}


float perlinNoise(float x, float y) {
  // 1 - Topleft, 2 - topright, 3 - bottom left, 4 - bottom right
  int xInd = (int)floor(x) % 256;
  int yInd = (int)floor(y) % 256;

  x -= floor(x);
  y -= floor(y);

  Vector2 DirectionTopRight = {x - 1.0, y};
  Vector2 DirectionTopLeft = {x, y};
  Vector2 DirectionBottomRight = {x - 1.0, y - 1.0};
  Vector2 DirectionBottomLeft = {x, y - 1.0};

  Vector2 GradientTopRight = grad(p[p[xInd + 1] + yInd]);
  Vector2 GradientTopLeft = grad(p[p[xInd] + yInd]);
  Vector2 GradientBottomRight = grad(p[p[xInd + 1] + yInd + 1]);
  Vector2 GradientBottomLeft = grad(p[p[xInd] + yInd + 1]);

  float dotTopRight = dotp(DirectionTopRight, GradientTopRight);
  float dotTopLeft = dotp(DirectionTopLeft, GradientTopLeft);
  float dotBottomRight = dotp(DirectionBottomRight, GradientBottomRight);
  float dotBottomLeft = dotp(DirectionBottomLeft, GradientBottomLeft);

  // Fade Values
  float u = fade(x);
  float v = fade(y);

  /*if (fabs(u - 0.5f) > 0.5f || fabs(v - 0.5f) > 0.5f) {
    std::cout << u << "\t" << v << "\n";
  }*/

  return lerp(lerp(dotTopRight, dotTopLeft, u),
              lerp(dotBottomLeft, dotBottomRight, u), v);
}

int main(void) {
  const int screenWidth = 512;
  const int screenHeight = 512;

  InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "perlins go brrrrrrrrrrrrr");

  SetTargetFPS(60);

  while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
    BeginDrawing();

    ClearBackground(BLACK);

    for (float y = 0; y < 512; y++) {
      for (float x = 0; x < 512; x++) {
        float n = perlinNoise(x / 256, y / 256);

        // if (n < 0 || n > 255) std::cout << n << "\n";
        n += 1;
        n /= 2;
        int c = round(n * 255);
        Color col{c, c, c, (unsigned char)255};
        DrawPixel(x, y, col);
      }
    }

    EndDrawing();
  }

  CloseWindow();

  return 0;
}
```

Update: i was not using normalized vectors. but still get same but better results; (i updated code)
As i see values are not repeating on the same points!
[image]

Update 2: Well i had some typo in my code about returning part and i fixed it but now grids are not "connected" to each other. (updated code)
[image]

Comment: Making a blind guess - something related to normalization.

Comment: Try to debug your code: add breakpoints, intermediate prints. Maybe you have an overflow somewhere.

Comment: `lerp(dotBottomLeft, dotBottomLeft, u)` can't be right. Also, permutations indexing look like something that can shoot you in the foot.

Comment: @Lodinn well i fixed that but i still got one problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the initial fixes, there's just one last step to make. You got the corners order mixed up - for bilinear interpolation, we are first interpolating along one axis, then along another, and the vertices have to come in proper order every time.

```
return lerp(lerp(dotTopLeft, dotTopRight, u),
            lerp(dotBottomLeft, dotBottomRight, u), v);
```

(I debugged this after rewriting it in Python, so it is possible that I have missed something else, but hopefully not... Feel free to ask questions if it is not working). The result I've got:

[image: Perlin noise 2nd octave]

As a side note, the reason you pass values over 1 to the Perlin noise generator is to generate higher octaves. You are using the 2nd octave in your code, passing `x / 64, y / 64` yields the 4th octave which looks like this:

[image: Perlin noise 4th octave]

Superimposing them allows for generation of more complex patterns. The reason I mention this is that calling the noise generator like `perlinNoise(x/256, y/256)` while iterating up to 511 conceals this purpose a little bit - a more idiomatic way would be

```
perlinNoise(x / w * octave, y / h * octave)
```

That way, you are clearly iterating over pixels of your target window, using fractional coordinates for noise generation and using the scale for the desired level of detail explicitly. A common use case adds several scales of noise, but dampens higher frequency ones so that the resulting surface looks somewhat realistic.

You can even use different scales for x and y! It can look pretty creative, too:

[image: Perlin noise different scales]